# What spacing to use for operator application?

Tags: math-mode

For example, `\sin 2` produces a space between sin and 2. But what space is it? Is it `\,`, `~`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\sin` is of class `\mathop` and `2` is a `\mathord` so will get `\thinmuskip` spacing added. This is the same space as `\,` although if you are needing to add this space in similar situations it would be better to declare an operator, or use `\operatorname{zzzz} 2` rather than `\mathrm{zzzz}\, 2`

Comment: @daleif it says `2` not `\2` (I say innocently)